# Build watch app to device

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, appcelerator, watchos-2, appcelerator-titanium

I am attempting to generate a Ti app (SDK 5.2.0.GA - using alloy) with a swift-os2 watch extension directly to device in App Studio. It runs fine on the iPhone and Watch simulator when testing but I get this error when attempting to run on device.

> [ERROR] :  iOS extension "watch" target "watch WatchKit App" has
>   invalid provisioning profile UUID in tiapp.xml. Did you mean?
>
> [ERROR] :  The provisioning profile "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx" is
>   tied to the application identifier "com.test.watch.*", however the
>   extension's identifier is "$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)".

I have redacted the profile id, but it does use a valid one that has been set up in tiapp.xml.

I have tried a project clean, and the removal of both the **build** and **Resources** directories but I still see this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the bundle identifier to "com.test.watch.foo"; something's wrong with the provisioning somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you've created provisioning profiles for the iOS app, WatchOs2 App and WatchOS2 App Extension (yes, that's three) and make sure the iPhone is in the first and the Watch is in the last two.

You can then [use Studio](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Integrate_a_WatchKit_App_Built_in_Xcode-section-43314566_IntegrateaWatchKitAppBuiltinXcode-ProvisioningProfiles) to configure them.

If you use a wildcard provisioning profile for the iOS app and both the iPhone and Watch are in it. Then you can leave the provisioning profiles for the WatchOS2 App and WatchOS2 App extension unconfigured and Titanium will automatically use that of the iOS app. You should see the following in the console log:

```
[WARN] :   iOS extension "Ti 5.2.0" target "<device>" is missing the Ti 5.2.0 WatchKit App provisioning profile UUID in tiapp.xml.
[WARN] :   Using the iOS app provisioning profile UUID "xxxxxxxx-7262-4b24-82cf-7969af384b4b"
[WARN] :   iOS extension "Ti 5.2.0" target "<device>" is missing the Ti 5.2.0 WatchKit Extension provisioning profile UUID in tiapp.xml.
[WARN] :   Using the iOS app provisioning profile UUID "xxxxxxxx-7262-4b24-82cf-7969af384b4b"
```

Comment: I have managed to get the app to install directly to device as suggested setting just the device option (with the associated watch app) but I could only get it to work using  iOS Team Prov Profile: * . If I use (for example) com.test.watch.*  in the device option I still get error I mentioned above. Still need to try with 3 separate profiles - thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that a) The iOS app, WatchOS2 App and WatchOS2 Extension all three use an app ID under that wildcard? b) iPhone and Apple Watch are in the provisioning profile?